# Postgres columns linked

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, constraints

**Context**: PostgreSQL database with a table `steps` with columns `subtype` and `type` (integer)

**Needs**: set the column `subtype` value to NULL if column `type` value not equals '4' on new record insert.

A good way to do this ? constraint ? trigger ?

Thanks

Comment: A good read of the manual would go a long way.  You can't change a value with a constraint, only stop someone setting it incorrectly. If you need it to be set automatically then you need a before insert/update trigger.  You can read up on triggers here: (for trigger functions) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html and (for the trigger itself) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: At the very least, you need a constraint on the table. You *can* write a trigger that essentially corrects what application code is trying to do, but you're better off fixing the application code. (If that's practical. It's not always practical, in which case write a trigger to fix the values.)

Comment: Enforce your requirement with a `CHECK` constraint, so that incorrect data cannot be saved. Then add a trigger that sets the data up that way if you can't fix the application to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is add a constraint:

```
CHECK (type = 4 OR subtype IS NULL) -- if type is 4, sub type may or may not be null
                                    -- if type is not 4, sub type must be null
```

Then if you need to you can write a simple trigger to set this, but in general you are better off raising app errors if necessary than using triggers because the application being notified that what it will get out is not what it saved is usually a good thing.